Generator of translations in a Riemannian manifold
Let $f$ be a smooth function from $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}$. We have that
\begin{equation}
e^{\vec{\tau}\cdot \vec{\nabla}}f(\vec{x})=f(\vec{x}-\vec{\tau})
\end{equation}
where $\vec{\tau}\in X$ is a vector and $\vec{\nabla}$ is the gradient operator. This is essentially the Taylor expansion of $f(\vec{x}-\vec{\tau})$ around $\vec{x}$.
What is the analog of this equation when $X$ is an arbitrary Riemannian manifold (especially when $X$ cannot be covered with a single coordinate chart)?
I understand that $X$ is generally not a vector space. However, given the exponential map, it seems natural to think of an operator that, when acting on a function evaluated at a point $p\in X$, would produce the function evaluated at a different point by following the geodesic that passes through $p$ with tangent vector $\vec{\tau}\in T_pX$.

For starters, open sets intersect in sets of measure zero only when they are disjoint.

That makes sense. I have edited my post to remove the second part of the question. I also now think that the analog of $e^{\vec{\tau}\cdot\vec{\nabla}}f(\vec{x})=f(\vec{x}-\vec{\tau})$ for Riemannian manifolds cannot be expressed without relying on the local coordinates, since it only makes sense in a local neighborhood. In that case, the same expression would be valid for Riemannian spaces. Maybe my question is a bit dumb...

What would you call a translation in a generic Riemannian manifold? Generically, there is not even a single nontrivial isometry.

@Didier I guess "moving along a geodesic", but I understand the concept breaks down once you reach the cut locus

@STU Moving along which geodesics? Translations in $\Bbb R^n$ correspond to moving along a family of parallel straight lines that foliates the whole space. You don't have such a feature in a Riemannian manifold.

@Didier But there is only one geodesic that passes through a point with a given tangent vector, right? I understand that you can only reach a neighborhood of the point in that manner and not the whole space. I guess I am just saying the concept only makes sense in local neighborhoods and not globally. I may just delete my post. I think my question does not make much sense

@STU Not sure if this is relevant, but maybe you are looking for a concept suck as that of geodesic spray (the wikipedia article is not very instructive, you might want to learn more elsewhere)

@Didier That is useful. Thank you

The Taylor formula has nothing to do with metrics. The partial derivatives act as generators along a a mesh considered as  a flat, cartesian lattice.
Any function like e.g. a metric translates by the simple fact that
$$f( x+a, \ y, \ \dots) = f(T_1(a) \mathbf x)  = \sum f_{k,l,\dots} \ (T_1(a)(x))^k y^l\dots = T_1(a) f(x) $$
because the identity $T^{-1} T$ can inserted between factors
$$(T(a) x)^2 = (T(a) x T^{-1}(a) T(a) x) = T_a(x^2)$$
If you use the components of the covariant derivative instead of the partial derivative, the metric is a 'constant of motion', the change is transfered to the translation of the coordinate frame by the application to the factors of th bilinear form.
$$(1+ t \nabla_1) G(e_i,e_k) =G((1+t \sum \Gamma^s_i1 e_s),e_k) + G(e_i,(1+t \sum \Gamma^s_k1 e_s)$$

This is the kind of things I am looking for. Is there an introductory reference you would recommend to read more about it?
